# Uniform convergence with respect to $k$ in the proof of Demoivre-Laplace Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-convergence, central-limit-theorem

I have some questions involving in the answer of the question in [this link.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091338/rigorous-real-analysis-proof-of-de-moivre-laplace-theorem)

The excerpts said that the convergence $$\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}\sim\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi npq}}e^{-x_k^2/2},$$
is uniform with respect to $k$. What is "with respect to $k$" means? Why is it uniform? I am confused with this because we have a uniform convergent sequence like $f_n(x)=x^n/n$ for $x\in(0,a)$ with fixed $a<1$. Do we have that this $x^n/n$ converges uniformly with respect to $x$ or what is it actually?

How can we show that this statement means that the left hand side converges uniformly? Since $k$ depends on $n$ in the sense that $n\rightarrow \infty$ and so does $k$ as in $(7.3.14)$. This really confuses me as the example $f_n(x)$ an $x$ and $n$ are independent. The uniform convergence concerns $2$ variables in function?

Furthermore, the uniform thing here is important as we can calculate the right in the sum
$$\sum_{a< x_k\le b}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi npq}}e^{-x_k^2/2}$$
instead of the left one (to prove $\int e^{-x^2/2}dx$ things)? It seems make sense (if it is uniform?) that the uniform summand can be exchanged between limit (of its asymptotic) and integral (in the range $(a,b)$) and we can obtain the result $(7.3.19)$. Please forgive my stupidities and thank you for your reply in advance.

Comment: Uniform in asymptotics means that the ratio of the two sides tends to $1$ as $n\to +\infty$ uniformly in $k$. In other words, you have a bound for the relative error which is the same for all $k$, it depends only on $n$.

Comment: In formula $$
\binom{n}{k}p^k q^{n - k}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi npq} }}e^{ - x_k^2 /2} (1 + f(n,k))
$$ where $f(n,k) \to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$ uniformly in $k$ ($k$ lies in an appropriate range).

Comment: Thank you @Gary